# How can I make apache ignite use all CPU power available for filtering cache?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, ignite

I'm trying to force Apache Ignite 1.5.0.final to use all the CPU power available on a single node to process local cache data in parallel however I can clearly see it is not using all the available cores.

Cache is created as follows:

```
    CacheConfiguration<Integer, MyObject> cfg = new CacheConfiguration<Integer, MyObject>();
    cfg.setSwapEnabled(false);
    cfg.setName(CACHE_NAME);
    cfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
    cfg.setMemoryMode(CacheMemoryMode.ONHEAP_TIERED);
    cfg.setBackups(0);
    cfg.setCopyOnRead(false);
    this.cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(CACHE_NAME);
```

CPU usage looks like only one thread is doing the work. When I switched the implementation to an ArrayList - not using Ignite, CPU usage gets to 400%.

This piece of code is used to filter the cache:

```
            IgniteCache<Integer, MyObject> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(CACHE_NAME);
            Spliterator<Entry<Integer, MyObject>> split = cache.localEntries().spliterator();
            Stream<MyObject> stream = StreamSupport.stream(split, true).map( entry -> entry.getValue());    
            aggregate.setCount(stream.filter(new SomePredicate()).count());
```

Did some profiling when running with Ignite and noticed there is only one Runnable thread at a time, while with an ArrayList got 3 or 4 doing the work.

Help much appreciated,

Bart

Answer (score 0):

`localEntries` returns iterator for internal Ignite data structures, so I don't think it's possible to split it using Java stream API without additional support. But you can parallelize the task by using `ScanQuery` which allows to iterate through a particular partition. Get the list of local partition numbers, create a separate query for each partition and execute queries in separate threads. The code will look like this:

```
// Get list of local partitions.
int[] partitions = ignite.affinity(CACHE_NAME).allPartitions(ignite.cluster().localNode());

// For each partition submit a task to a thread pool.
for (final int partition : partitions) {
    executor.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            ScanQuery<Integer, MyObject> query = new ScanQuery<>();

            query.setPartition(partition);
            query.setLocal(true);

            QueryCursor<Cache.Entry<Integer, MyObject>> cursor = cache.query(query);

            for (Cache.Entry<Integer, MyObject> entry : cursor) {
                // ...
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  
Sounds very promising!  
Will give it a try and see if I can fine tune the number of partitions.

Comment: Hi @Valentin

I did the change you suggested.
I used two types of executor service - one I created on my own, the other as `threadPool = ignite.executorService(ignite.cluster().forLocal());`

Looks like CPU utlization is much bigger but they seem to be blocked somehow.
With a simple ArrayList I get my processing of 1 million objects done within 108ms, with Ignite the best I can get at the moment is > 1s.
Looked which threads do the filtering of cache and in the profiler they are blocked most of the time.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Bart, I don't think they really block somewhere, because the whole process is local, there is no I/O. But if you have any additional information (thread dumps, etc.), please provide it. In any case, comparison with `ArrayList` is not really fare. Ignite is a distributed system that allows to scale not only within one server, but across several servers, and designed to be used in highly concurrent scenarios. `ArrayList` on the other hand is a single-threaded data structure.

Comment: I will provide some more detailed information as soon as possible. I know what Ignite is and the comparision to the ArrayList was just to be able to see the overhead of managing a possible grid. I am fully aware of the capabilities of a distributed grid but if can't make it process a few miliion of objects on a single node with a few cpus with my SLA I won't be able to scale it to several hundred millions of objects within my budget. BWT ArrayList with the Java streams and fork-join support behaves very well - if I can get Ignite to run 2 or 3 times slower on a single node I will be happy.

Comment: they were definitely not blocked on I/O - that is for sure. My bad, I am afraid I put too much load on the app (1 mln objects) with 4GB of memory and GC was doing its hard work :/. Right now I have limited the working size to 100k objects and it looks like there's a lot of processing going in org.apache.ignite.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller.unmarshal. I simply want to see what my limitations on a single ignite node are - to be able too see if I can scale it to meet my goal (don't want to have a cluster of 500 nodes each holding 500k objects). Thanks in advance for advice

Comment: would it make sense to disable in memory serialization and store POJOs? Is it feasible? I believe it will slow down rebalancing and repartitioning not sure how it affects GC etc.